# Odoo 10 Dashboard Module icon issue

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

I am using Odoo 10e on my server.

I am facing issue for image icon for app the modules.

Is there any suggestion to resolve it ?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think, you faced issue when you restore database. If so, then try with upgrade *base* module with restored database.

You can upgrade base module from the terminal or GUI.

- From Terminal:

  - Append at the end of start command of Odoo. `-u all -d restored_database_name`
- From GUI:

  - Go to `Apps => Apps => remove Apps filter and search base` Open it and click on upgrade button.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it will update base module of default odoo, Also it will update all of our customised modules as well.
Is there no any other option ?

Comment: I am not sure if any other options are available to resolve it. But as per my answer that's the standard way to update it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by updating the Odoo Module "Base". In some cases I also had to delete some records from the ir_attachments table, just the ones with error in the logs:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log | grep "No such file or directory"
```

Tailing shows some records like this

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/var/lib/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/filestore/mydomain/e6/e6663e85127fff2d471b38e8f6de1aa1af8b76f9'
....
```

Then in postgres:

```
DELETE FROM ir_attachment WHERE store_fname LIKE '% e6663e85127fff2d471b38e8f6de1aa1af8b76f9%';
```